# Generating a synthetic dataset from a latent class model

Tags: latent-class, synthetic-data

In latent class analysis, the  estimated model paramters are class sizes and item-response probablities in each class.

Based on these basic parameters, is it possible to generate a synthetic sample of size `n` that fits the estimated model? If so, are there ways to do that in R?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the simsem package. It probably does what you want, or if not, you can tweek it for your particular case. Certainly, if you can fit your model using lavaan, you can simulate such a model using simsem.

Comment: This is not my field but another answer has been posted that should probably have been, in part, a comment on this one ("The previous answer is incorrect. simsem simulates data for structural equation modeling, not for latent class analysis.) - I thought I would notify you so that you might have the opportunity to respond.

Comment: Point taken. I wrongly believed that lavaan can fit a latent class model, but apparently that is still on the project's "to do" list. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is incorrect. `simsem` simulates data for structural equation modeling, not for latent class analysis.

`poLCA.simdata()` function of R package `poLCA` does what you want. Check the [documentation, p.15](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/poLCA/poLCA.pdf).

Comment: Part of this answer is really a comment on another answer - when you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.

Comment: @Silverfish yes, thank you, that's why I added the comment to my answer.